# SQL Server 2005 update query with left join not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do an Update query with a left join in SQL Server 2005 but for some reason it's not working.

[EDIT: "not working" - sorry, this means that the update isn't running. Records aren't updated. I'm running this Update query in a SRSS report, because the CRM I'm using doesn't allow direct access to the database - it runs Selects, Updates, Inserts, Deletes fine but gives you no useful error messages if things don't work as expected. Operating in the dark unfortunately!]

My SQL statement is this:

```
UPDATE [tblSlots]
SET [tblSlots].[PublishedStartTime] = '10:00'
FROM tblSlots
LEFT JOIN tblDays ON tblSlots.SlotDayID = tblDays.DayID
WHERE tblDays.Published = 1
```

If I take out the `LEFT JOIN` line and just filter on e.g. a `tblSlots.SlotID`, the update works fine.

But I'd like to be able to update the slots on ALL published days at once.

(I tried it as just a JOIN, but that didn't work either...)

I'm sure it's something terribly obvious...

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Side Comment: Does tblDays have only one record in it?  It looks like your update would update every record that had ever been run in tblDays.  I Would think you would have something like WHERE … AND tblDays.DateOfPublication = ’03-15-2019’ .

Comment: Try playing with a similar select first - that will help you see how the sql is being interpreted.  SELECT s.*, d.*  FROM tblSlots s   LEFT JOIN tblDays d ON tblSlots.SlotDayID = tblDays.DayID  WHERE  tblDays.Published = 1

Comment: 1. Using `WHERE tblDays.Published = 1` turns your OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN 2. The phase "not working" is very ambiguous. What is the *actual* result when you run the query above? What result did you *expect* instead?

Comment: Hello, sorry I've updated the question with more detail on what's not working.

Comment: @SqlSurfer tblDays right now only has 8 or so test records, but eventually will have c. 60 records per year. I would probably extend the WHERE to restrict it to published Days *this year*, if I can get the basic update working. And yes, tried a SELECT with the left join and it worked fine, seemingly. (i.e. the data displayed what I expected it to...)

Comment: It seems that a simple update using one table, no joins, will work, but as soon as you add a JOIN statement, it stops working. As I'm not getting any useful error messages from this system, it's hard to know if there is a good reason for it failing or not... Using SRSS reports to do update queries definitely isn't the usual way of doing things, but it's the only route I've got for running SQL updates on this system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query syntax looks fine to me, and as you said it runs fine until you try to do an update. This is a shot in the dark, but if the issue is with updating while selecting from multiple tables, then perhaps simply changing your query to not join to the tblDays might work.

```
UPDATE [tblSlots]
--SET [tblSlots].[PublishedStartTime] = '10:00'
SET [tblSlots].[PublishedStartTime] = (select SomeValue from tblDays where DayID = SlotDayID) --If a value is needed from Day table
FROM tblSlots
Where SlotDayID in (select DayID from tblDays WHERE Published = 1 and DayID is not null)
```

Comment: (I'm still stuck with the problem of not being able to draw data from the related tables to use for the Update bit, though....)

Comment: You may be able to get Day table values with a subquery, I updated the answer with this approach.

Comment: I had this very thought just as I was going to sleep last night - thanks very much, your code worked spot on!

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
UPDATE [tblSlots]
SET [tblSlots].[PublishedStartTime] = '10:00'

FROM [tblSlots] ,
(
    SELECT DayID FROM
    [tblSlots]
    LEFT JOIN tblDays 
    ON tblSlots.SlotDayID = tblDays.DayID
    WHERE tblDays.Published = 1
) AS [Data_Days]

WHERE 
[Data_Days].DayId = [tblSlots].SlotDayID
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @skyflakes I tried this, but the records didn't update. As I don't any information from this system on errors, I don't know why it didn't work... thanks for trying!